# How to send two different emails (poss customer / thank for submitting) simultaneously with freeform?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a simple working contact form that emails a specific person in a company possible customer information. However, the client also wants a confirmation sent to the potential customer when the customer submits the form containing a link and some other general info so that then can return to the "thank you" url, which has some helpful information.

How do you send two different emails at the same time to two a regular email address but also the email inputed in a form?

I doesn't seem you can use {email} to email the person who submitted the form.

```
 {exp:freeform:form 
        form:id="employee-form-wrap" 
        collection="Employee Relocation Form"
        template="employee-relocation-form" 

        return="contact/thank-you"
        notify="contact@mycompany.com"
        }

 {exp:freeform:form 
            form:id="employee-form-wrap" 
            collection="Employee Relocation Form Thank You Confirmation Email"
            template="Employee-Relocation-Form-Thank-You-Confirmation-Email" 
            notify="{email}"
        }

        <p><span>* </span>Indicates required field</p>

        <div>
            <label for="name">Name <span class="req">*</span></label><br>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""  class="validate[required] text-input">
        </div>                  
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email <span class="req">*</span></label><br>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value=""  class="validate[required,custom[email]]">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="phone">Phone Number</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="">
        </div>
        <li class="screen-reader">
            <label for="honeepot">Don't put anything here</label>
            <input type="text" name="honeepot" id="honeepot" />
        </li>

        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" >

        {/exp:freeform:form}
```

{/exp:freeform:form}

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Freeform docs under "Notifications" you'll see there is an option to notify both the admin as well as the user: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#parameters. And they each have their own email templates so you can format the emails to each person however you want.

Comment: Benek, is there a way to use two different templates? One would be for the possible customer information and another for the customer so that they receive an another type of email with a url we want them to have? Using notify_user="yes"?

Comment: Yes. You can set up different email templates in the Notifications settings: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/control_panel/#notifications, and then use admin_notify with admin_notification_template, and notify_user and user_notification_template to say which templates to use for each email.

Comment: I have all the required field and the BOTH templates made but it still doesn't email. Do you see anything wrong with it?{exp:freeform:form
 form:id="employee-reloction-form" 
 collection="Employee Relocation Form"
  
 user_notification_template="employee-relocation-form-thank-you-confirmation-email"
 notify_user="yes" 
 user_email_field="email"

 return="http://www.company.com/thankyou"
 admin_notify="example@example.com"
 admin_notification_template="employee-relocation-form"
 notify_admin="yes"

Comment: Maybe someone from Solspace will be able to chime in with more help.